# How to bring the jquery dialog box in front of a modal div?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

The way how my practice program works is that the admin users can click a person name from a list an after it, a large modal div would pop-out that shows the information of the person on the list. The admin can the opt to remove some unnecessary information about the user. The admin can click a button to delete it then a jquery dialog box should pop up to confirm. Right now, I can't see the dialog box pop out but when I close the modal box, the dialog box lies behind it. Is there a way that I can transfer the jquery dialog box in front of a modal div?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to increase the zindex of your dialog so it's value is larger than that of the modal div
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-zIndex